# How to create a table with two fields as User model type

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to make a messaging app in my Django project, I want the table to have three fields, "`sender`" "`title`" "`message`" "`receiver`". Title and Message can be declared as char-field. But I cannot make sender and receiver as two ForeignKey Field. I don't know what to use here. Can anyone help me figure this out?

I tried to declare both fields as ForeignKey with the user model. But it didn't work.

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
# Create your models here.
class msgs(models.Model):
    to = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    frm = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    body = models.CharField(max_length=2000)
```

ERRORS:

```
msgs.msgs.frm: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'msgs.frm' clashes with reverse accessor for 'msgs.to'.<br>
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'msgs.frm' or 'msgs.to'.<br>
msgs.msgs.frm: (fields.E305) Reverse query name for 'msgs.frm' clashes with reverse query name for 'msgs.to'.<br>
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'msgs.frm' or 'msgs.to'.<br>
msgs.msgs.to: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'msgs.to' clashes with reverse accessor for 'msgs.frm'.<br>
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'msgs.to' or 'msgs.frm'.<br>
msgs.msgs.to: (fields.E305) Reverse query name for 'msgs.to' clashes with reverse query name for 'msgs.frm'.<br>
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'msgs.to' or 'msgs.frm'.<br>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message says, because you have two relationships to the same model, you need to specify a related name for them.

```
class msgs(models.Model):
    to = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='to_user')
    frm = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='from_user')
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    body = models.CharField(max_length=2000)
```

A few other tips:

- Use uppercase for your class name (class Message, or class Msg)
- Use a models.ForeignKey instead of a models.OneToOneField if you want the users to have multiple conversations